# jQuery Highlight element on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, release, highlight

I have a list of values in a drop down style select box e.g.

```
<select id="places">
<option>Italy</option>
<option>France</option>
<option>Germany</option>
<option>Spain</option>
</select>
```

I also have the same list of values in a div on my page
e.g.

```
<div>
<span>Italy</span>
<span>France</span>
<span>Germany</span>
<span>Spain</span>
</div>
```

Using JQuery, I want to have it so - when a value in the dropdown is selected, the equivalent option in the div is briefly highlighted.

I've been struggling with the jQuery highlight plugin, but I believe the quicker way may be to use the highlight class of JjQuery UI. Apologies in advance for being a noob :)

Comment: "briefly highlighted" - .1 second, 1 minute, describe what this means.  Please show what you have attempted (code wise) at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [highlight effect from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/):

```
$('#places').change(function() {
  $('div span:contains(' + $(this).val() + ')').effect('highlight', {}, 1000)
})
```

When an item from the drop-down is selected, the span [containing](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) the respective text of the [selected item](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) is run through a animation of its background color ("highlight" effect) provided by the plugin.

[Demo here.](http://jsbin.com/eqagi/)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery UI plugin you can use the following

```
$('#places').change(function(){
    $('span:contains('+ $(this).val() +')').effect('highlight', {color: 'red'}, 3000);
});
```

Change the color and 3000 as required.