# Highlight a select / dropdown with a class when its open or is has a option other than the initial default selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, this sounds super simple!! but its driving me crazy and giving me brain fade :)

Say I have a basic select box like:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="">--- select ---</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>
```

What I would like is for the "highlight" class to be added to the select during the following states:

1. The select is in its dropped down / open state
2. The select has a valid option selected (i.e. One or Two)

But it need's to have the class removed if the select is closed back without a valid selection (i.e. it's changed back to "--- select ---")

Sounds easy!!

I tried this which seemed the obvious way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#test').focus(function () {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    })

    $('#test').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != '') $(this).addClass('highlight');
        else $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    })
});
```

But it doesn't quite 100% work but it's close, the problem is if you select something then change it back to "--- select ---" but then you don't loose focus of the drop down and re-click it then it does not add the "highlight" class again.

I have tried many combinations of adding extra events like click but I cannot seem to get it working exactly how I would like. It's almost like I need a "opening" event on the select but obviously that does not exist.

Have I missed something seriously obvious here? as I'm a competent web developer who has spent a couple of hours trying to do this!! haha... But it is pretty late here in NZ so that's my excuse if I have :)

Thanks, Carl

Comment: Unfortunately there are no events for dropped down / open states of `select` element.

Comment: check the 'highlight' class is present in css.. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804165/jquery-highlight-element-on-select-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('select').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').find('option').css('color', '#000');
}).on('blur', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    if (this.value.length) $(this).addClass('highlight');
}).on('change', function() {
    if (this.value.length) $(this).addClass('highlight');
    else $(this).removeClass('highlight')
});​
​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GSmJ5/3/)

Comment: @user1259167 why down vote? what problem with my code? please comment.

Comment: may the SO not put the down-vote, some-other will made it.user1259167 only have 3 reputation so,he/she not able to down-vote. many-times it's happen for me also.

Comment: @krish hmm, but aim of m comment is to know the cause of downvote? thanks

Comment: your code is works fine. but i not have any idea about the down-vote. thanks for this code.

Comment: I have not made any down vote!! just testing out the code now :)

Comment: It still has the issue I mentioned though, open the drop down, click "One", open the drop down again, click "--- select ---", then open the drop down again and it will not be highlighted :(

Comment: Check out this tweaked version, which highlights the issue better... basically I never want to see the dropdown open with grey text which is possible with this jquery doing the above: http://jsfiddle.net/GSmJ5/2/

Comment: Ahh ok, yeah see what you have done there. I will put it in situ on my project later and see how it goes. I'm guessing it won't be 100% browser compatible going back due to styling the option's but this may be as close as I can get :) Thanks!!

Comment: @user1259167 if it closer to your target, then you should accept it as answer